# Проверка наличия данных этой записи перед DELETE?

Tags: postgresql

Нужно выполнить запрос

```
DELETE FROM directories_data  WHERE id=56
```

Но в таблице directories_data и directories_data_2 этот id может использоваться.

```
SELECT id FROM directories_data WHERE data ILIKE '%id=56%' LIMIT 1;
SELECT id FROM directories_data_2 WHERE data ILIKE '%id=56%' LIMIT 1;
```

Как безопасно удалить эту запись проверив, что её нигде нет (2 select запроса)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM directories_data d 
    WHERE id = 56 AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM directories_data WHERE data ILIKE '%id=' || d.id || '%') AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM directories_data_2 WHERE data ILIKE '%id=' || d.id || '%');
```